# While using the below piece of code, i receive an error "No Overload for method 'Insert' takes 1 argument

Tags: c#-4.0

```
worksheet
    .get_Range(rangeForCount, Type.Missing)
    .EntireColumn
    .Insert(
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftToRight);
```

Comment: So how many arguments does it take then?

Comment: Perhaps this will help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7636745/writing-to-new-columns-in-excel-using-c-sharp

Comment: Thanks @Tony Hopkinson. I was able to figure out the reason for the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[That `Insert` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.insert.aspx) has a unique overload and takes in ***two*** arguments.

You seem to have specified `Shift` but not `CopyOrigin`.